# 2 AIR applications directly communicating with each other in real time ie Peer to Peer (P2P)

Tags: air, communication

Building a installation that requires 2 different kiosks to communicate with each other. I'd like to use Adobe AIR to create the individual applications.

My question is
Is it possible for 2 separate AIR applications to DIRECTLY communicate with each other in real time, without any server to act as mediator?

Ideally the only data that would be transferred would be json based.

Adobe has the beta Cirrus RTMFP option but requires internet access to initiate the communication. I can't rely on internet access so not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

If applications are on same network, you can use P2P communications. Googling "flash p2p" should provide examples.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this directly in AIR, you'd use the [`Socket`/`ServerSocket`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html) classes (or derivatives).

At the library level, check out [Cocoon P2P](http://code.google.com/p/cocoon-p2p/), in beta.